# How to add columns without using dense_rank() function in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

Basically, I have a this query that works well. Using `MIN` and `MAX` functions, I can retrieve the 2 names with their corresponding `Tickets` and `Total` columns.

```
WITH Sales AS
(
    SELECT  
        *, 
        RN = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DeviceID, EmployeeID
                                ORDER BY StartTime)
    FROM    
        TicketSales
),
Aggregates AS
(
    SELECT  
        CONVERT(DATE, StartTime) AS [Date],
        DeviceID AS [Device ID], 
        MIN(CASE WHEN ts.RN = 1 THEN emp.Name END) AS [Name1],
        COUNT(CASE WHEN ts.RN = 1 THEN TicketID END) AS [Tickets1],
        SUM(CASE WHEN ts.RN = 1 THEN TotalPrice END) AS [Total1], 
        MAX(CASE WHEN ts.RN = 2 THEN emp.Name END) AS [Name2],
        COUNT(CASE WHEN ts.RN = 2 THEN TicketID END) AS [Tickets2],
        SUM(CASE WHEN ts.RN = 2 THEN TotalPrice END) AS [Total2],
        COUNT(TicketID) AS [Total Issued Tickets],
        SUM(TotalPrice) AS [Total Amount]
    FROM    
        Sales AS ts
    INNER JOIN 
        Employee AS emp ON ts.EmployeeID = emp.SysID
    WHERE   
        CONVERT(DATE, StartTime) BETWEEN '07/08/201' AND '07/08/201'
    GROUP BY 
        DeviceID, CONVERT(DATE, StartTime)
)
```

But, how can I add Name3, Tickets3, Total3 ORDER BY date?

Expected result

```
    date| name1|  ticket1|  total1|  name2|  ticket2|  total2|  name3|  ticket3|  total3
07/08/18|   n1 |     t1  |   tot1 |    n2 |     t2  |    tot2|    n3 |  t3         tot3
```

Each day has at least 3 shift, that is why i had 3 Names and its corresponding data.

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post a minimal question which we can easily digest.  This is a pretty large query, and you've given almost zero information about what it is doing.

Comment: *sample data*. *expected results*. These would really help us to work out *what you're trying to do*. Because, for instance, it's unclear to me why you think `MIN` is correct for one of your results but `MAX` is correct for the other.

Comment: @LukStorms see edits, thank you

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever see edits, thank you

Comment: Yes, that's the expected result (although more than a single row would usually be more helpful). But you also know *what the input data looks like*. We don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it just needs some changes in the OVER clause of the DENSE_RANK.
And then add the aggregations for the 3th employee.

The WHERE clause for the date could also be put in the CTE.

A SQL Fiddle to test can be found [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4040d/1/0)

**Sql:**

```
WITH SALES AS
(
  SELECT DeviceID, EmployeeID, StartTime, TicketID, TotalPrice, 
   dense_rank() over (partition by DeviceID, convert(date,StartTime) order by EmployeeID) as RNK
  FROM TicketSales
  WHERE CONVERT(date,StartTime) BETWEEN CAST('2018-08-07' AS DATE) AND CAST('2018-08-07' AS DATE)
)
SELECT
 CONVERT(date,ts.StartTime) as [Date],
 ts.DeviceID as [Device ID], 

 MAX(CASE WHEN ts.RNK = 1 THEN emp.Name END) as [Name1],
 COUNT(CASE WHEN ts.RNK = 1 THEN ts.TicketID END) as [Tickets1],
 SUM(CASE WHEN ts.RNK = 1 THEN ts.TotalPrice END) as [Total1],

 MAX(CASE WHEN ts.RNK = 2 THEN emp.Name END) as [Name2],
 COUNT(CASE WHEN ts.RNK = 2 THEN ts.TicketID END) as [Tickets2],
 SUM(CASE WHEN ts.RNK = 2 THEN ts.TotalPrice END) as [Total2],

 MAX(CASE WHEN ts.RNK = 3 THEN emp.Name END) as [Name3],
 COUNT(CASE WHEN ts.RNK = 3 THEN ts.TicketID END) as [Tickets3],
 SUM(CASE WHEN ts.RNK = 3 THEN ts.TotalPrice END) as [Total3],

 COUNT(ts.TicketID) as [Total Issued Tickets],
 SUM(ts.TotalPrice) AS [Total Amount]
FROM SALES as ts
JOIN Employee as emp ON ts.EmployeeID = emp.SysID
GROUP BY CONVERT(date, ts.StartTime), ts.DeviceID;
```

Another way is to group already in the CTE.
And use row_number this time.
This makes it possible to list the employee's by the first issued ticket.

**Sql:**

```
WITH SALES AS
(
SELECT DeviceID, EmployeeID, 
 CONVERT(date,StartTime) AS StartDate,
 MIN(StartTime) AS MinStartTime, 
 COUNT(TicketID) AS TotalTickets,
 SUM(TotalPrice) AS TotalPrice,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DeviceID, CONVERT(date,StartTime) ORDER BY MIN(StartTime)) AS RN
FROM TicketSales
WHERE CONVERT(date,StartTime) BETWEEN CAST('2018-08-07' AS DATE) AND CAST('2018-08-07' AS DATE)
GROUP BY DeviceID, EmployeeID, CONVERT(date,StartTime)
)
SELECT
 ts.StartDate as [Date],
 ts.DeviceID as [Device ID], 

 MAX(CASE WHEN ts.RN = 1 THEN emp.Name END) as [Name1],
 SUM(CASE WHEN ts.RN = 1 THEN ts.TotalTickets END) as [Tickets1],
 SUM(CASE WHEN ts.RN = 1 THEN ts.TotalPrice END) as [Total1],

 MAX(CASE WHEN ts.RN = 2 THEN emp.Name END) as [Name2],
 SUM(CASE WHEN ts.RN = 2 THEN ts.TotalTickets END) as [Tickets2],
 SUM(CASE WHEN ts.RN = 2 THEN ts.TotalPrice END) as [Total2],

 MAX(CASE WHEN ts.RN = 3 THEN emp.Name END) as [Name3],
 SUM(CASE WHEN ts.RN = 3 THEN ts.TotalTickets END) as [Tickets3],
 SUM(CASE WHEN ts.RN = 3 THEN ts.TotalPrice END) as [Total3],

 SUM(ts.TotalTickets) as [Total Issued Tickets],
 SUM(ts.TotalPrice) AS [Total Amount]
FROM SALES as ts
JOIN Employee as emp ON ts.EmployeeID = emp.SysID
GROUP BY ts.StartDate, ts.DeviceID;
```

SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a436e/7/0)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I really appreciate it. By the way that given names are supposed to be a shifting schedule, Name1 is the 1st shift, name2 is the 2nd shift, name3 is the 3rd shift and it is based by time of the day . .

Comment: @JerwenReloz So does that mean that the example fiddle in this answer is okay?

Comment: I'll come to you real quick, need to test the query. thanks.

Comment: When i test the query. two data are interchanged, say, John Doe must be on 1st shift but it displayed on 2nd shift column. . I dont know why :(

Comment: @JerwenReloz Good that you found your solution. So then I guess you can close your question by approving one of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

@Jerwen Reloz, That is fine. you can easily add the new columns by adding them in cases where rownumber RN=3. See the modified version below:

```
WITH Sales AS
(
    SELECT  
        *, 
        RN = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DeviceID, EmployeeID
                                ORDER BY StartTime)
    FROM    
        TicketSales
),
Aggregates AS
(
    SELECT  
        CONVERT(DATE, StartTime) AS [Date],
        DeviceID AS [Device ID], 
        MIN(CASE WHEN ts.RN = 1 THEN emp.Name END) AS [Name1],
        COUNT(CASE WHEN ts.RN = 1 THEN TicketID END) AS [Tickets1],
        SUM(CASE WHEN ts.RN = 1 THEN TotalPrice END) AS [Total1], 
        MAX(CASE WHEN ts.RN = 2 THEN emp.Name END) AS [Name2],
        COUNT(CASE WHEN ts.RN = 2 THEN TicketID END) AS [Tickets2],
        SUM(CASE WHEN ts.RN = 2 THEN TotalPrice END) AS [Total2],
        COUNT(CASE WHEN ts.RN = 3 THEN TicketID END) AS [Tickets3],
        SUM(CASE WHEN ts.RN = 3 THEN TotalPrice END) AS [Total3],
        COUNT(TicketID) AS [Total Issued Tickets],
        SUM(TotalPrice) AS [Total Amount]
    FROM    
        Sales AS ts
    INNER JOIN 
        Employee AS emp ON ts.EmployeeID = emp.SysID
    WHERE   
        CONVERT(DATE, StartTime) BETWEEN '07/08/201' AND '07/08/201'
    GROUP BY 
        DeviceID, CONVERT(DATE, StartTime)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I really appreciate it. By the way that given names are supposed to be a shifting schedule, Name1 is the 1st shift, name2 is the 2nd shift, name3 is the 3rd shift and it is based by time of the day . .